# Display the datatable in xml c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I'm trying to create a xml file with the data in my dataTable. Ultimately, this is what I want to create

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<regisApts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <JobList>
    <Job id="1245">
      <Date>2010-07-25</Date>
      <Reason>No Access 1</Reason>
      <Comment>Tenant is on holiday</Comment>
      <ExternalJobNumber>123456</ExternalJobNumber>
    </Job>
    <Job id="">
      <Date>2010-07-26</Date>
      <Reason>No Access 2</Reason>
      <Comment>Tenant out at work</Comment>
      <ExternalJobNumber>123456</ExternalJobNumber>
    </Job>
    <Job id="1453">
      <Date>2010-07-25</Date>
      <Reason>No Access 1</Reason>
      <Comment>Tenant in hospital</Comment>
    </Job>
  </JobList>
</regisApts>
```

I managed to generate a xml with foreach, but it's overiding the xml when inserting the next row. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    xmlCostCode = row["CostCode"].ToString();
    xmlReason = row["Reason"].ToString();
    xmlComment = row["PropertyCode"].ToString();
    xmlFilePath = xmlFolderPath + "test" + ".xml";

    xmlContent = "<JobList><Job Id=\"" + xmlCostCode + "\"><Date>2017-07-18</Date><Reason>" + xmlReason + "</Reason><Comment>" + xmlComment + "</Comment></Job></JobList>";

    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
    xdoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
}
```

Results I get

```
<JobList>
    <Job id="1245">
      <Date>2010-07-25</Date>
      <Reason>No Access 1</Reason>
      <Comment>Tenant is on holiday</Comment>
      <ExternalJobNumber>123456</ExternalJobNumber>
    </Job>
<JobList>
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: @RobertJuneau I edited the question and added the results I get

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable in the first place? Why not a strongly typed object, such as `List<Job>`?

Comment: Have you tried [`WriteXml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes. It create nicely with the WriteXml. but <JobList> and <Job Id=""> are not columns from datatable. So I dont know how to create those attributes and elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you do

```
 XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
 xdoc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
 xdoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

It writes over your previous document with the most recent row, so try

```
xmlContent = "<regisApts xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><JobList>";
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   xmlCostCode = row["CostCode"].ToString();
   xmlReason = row["Reason"].ToString();
   xmlComment = row["PropertyCode"].ToString();
   xmlFilePath = xmlFolderPath + "test" + ".xml";

   xmlContent = xmlContent +"<Job Id=\"" + xmlCostCode + "\"><Date>2017-07-18</Date><Reason>" + xmlReason + "</Reason><Comment>" + xmlComment + "</Comment></Job>";

}
xmlContent = xmlContent +"</JobList></regisApts>";
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xmlContent);
xdoc.Save(xmlFilePath);
```

This way you are building the string with each row and once that is done you create the XML doc.

Comment: Depending on how many Rows are in the DataTable, it may be safer to use a StringBuilder. Also, if you're manually generating the XML text you can just append the rest of the opening and closing tags in the StringBuilder and and write it out to file using a StreamWritter.

Comment: This is not working for me, I get unexpected closing tag error

Comment: @KMR whats the faulty closing tag?

Comment: @RobertJuneau Sorry my bad. I missed one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you are using `for`...`each`, I am assuming you are building the XML up textually. I recommend that you *not* do that, and instead look into XML serialization. Microsoft provides an example here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815813/how-to-serialize-an-object-to-xml-by-using-visual-c

Essentially, you create an object representation for your XML (your data table is likely this already), create a serializer for your type, and then run it, outputting to a stream (file stream, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication65
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("CostCode", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Reason", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Comment", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("PropertyCode", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1245, DateTime.Parse("2010-07-25"), "No Access 1", "Tenant is on holiday", 123456 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { null, DateTime.Parse("2010-07-26"), "No Access 2", "Tenant out at work", 123456 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1453, DateTime.Parse("2010-07-25"), "No Access 1", "Tenant in hospital", null });

            string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<regisApts xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                "<JobList></JobList></regisApts>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(header);
            XElement jobList = doc.Descendants("JobList").FirstOrDefault();

            foreach(DataRow row in dt.AsEnumerable())
            {
                XElement job = new XElement("Job", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("id", row.Field<object>("CostCode") == null ? "" : row.Field<int>("CostCode").ToString()),
                    new XElement("Date", row.Field<DateTime>("Date").ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                    new XElement("Reason", row.Field<string>("Reason")),
                    new XElement("Comment", row.Field<string>("Comment")),
                    new XElement("ExternalJobNumber", row.Field<object>("PropertyCode") == null ? "" : row.Field<int>("PropertyCode").ToString())
                });
                jobList.Add(job);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to use a DataTable for some reason (I don't see a good one here) then you should use Generics to return your data as a strongly typed object. Something like

```
List<JobList> jobList = new List<JobList>();
```

Then use a function to serialize your JobList class into XML. Just simply pass your class to the function as an object. I prefer not to use the XMLSerializer class as it's bloated and has to create a temp file while serializing your object. I'd use something like this which is significantly faster.

```
public XElement GetAsXml(object obj)
    {
        XElement xelement = new XElement(obj.GetType().Name); 

        PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            object propertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj);

            if(propertyValue != null)
            {
                XElement xProperty = new XElement(prop.Name, propertyValue);
                xelement.Add(xProperty);
            }
        }

        return xelement;
    }
```